# How can i add new parameter to an API to register a new atribute

Tags: magento2

How can i add new parameter to an API for example /V1/customers for register a new atribute phone for example.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:Create **etc/registration.php** file

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sunarc_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step 2: Create **etc/module.xml** file.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sunarc_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create a customer attribute named Phone Number in **Setup/InstallData.php** file

```
<?php

namespace Sunarc\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * [__construct]
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory                          $attributeSetFactory
    )
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface   $context
    )
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(
            ['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
            ->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /**
         * @var $attributeSet AttributeSet
         */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'phone_number',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Phone Number',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position' => 366,
                'system' => false,
                'global' => true,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false
            ]
        );

        //add attribute to attribute set
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'phone_number')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']]);

        $attribute->save();

    }
}
```

Step 4: Run commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
chmod -R 755 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Step 5:Create customers through Rest API with custom attribute
Api used : <base_url>/rest/all/V1/customers

Body :

```
{ 
  "customer": 
  {
  "email": "test2@gmail.com", 
  "firstname": "x", 
  "lastname": "y", 
  "website_id":1, 
  "group_id":1, 
  "custom_attributes": 
  [ 
    { 
    "attribute_code": "phone_number", 
    "value": "7896541230" 
    } 
  ]

},
"password": "admin@123"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "group_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2023-01-09 07:57:05",
    "updated_at": "2023-01-09 07:57:05",
    "created_in": "Default Store View",
    "email": "test2@gmail.com",
    "firstname": "x",
    "lastname": "y",
    "store_id": 1,
    "website_id": 1,
    "addresses": [],
    "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
        "is_subscribed": false
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "phone_number",
            "value": "7896541230"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You absolutely do not want to grant write access to executable or system files to all users under any circumstances. You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and learn about the Unix permissions model before you try to use it again. If this happened on a system with Internet access, check whether an intruder could have exploited this to escalate their privileges.